# Dual monitors, screen resolution, xorg.conf.d

Tags: ati, multiple-monitors, resolution

I do a lot of RTFM but this one has got me stuck.

I have Ubuntu Studio 12.04 Precise Pangolin with XFCE as its default desktop.

My old HIS ATI Radeon 9250 graphics card was adding red crud across the screen with the generic driver, but downloading the proprietary "fglrx" driver makes it work cleanly. The trouble is the Catalyst control centre refuses to recognise my old card so I must do some manual configuring to make sure both the DVI and VGA monitors are capable of the correct screen resolution (both 1280x1024) and a dual display.

It used to be easier to just edit the existing xorg.conf file and add another resolution and so forth, but now there are automatic xorg.conf.d directories (more than one) with scant documentation.

Creating a generic xorg.conf with a terminal command creates every setting imaginable. What I want to do is create the simplest conf file which just tells the system the following:

- My VGA monitor can do 1280x1024 60Hz

  The two monitors together may be 2560x1024 width

  The VGA monitor on the right

  I might need to specify Xinerama if it's needed

Thank you. I don't think I need to bore you with log files, but please ask for further info.

Mike

Answer (score 1):

Please see the following for my answer to this question on another site:

https://superuser.com/questions/438699/adding-dual-monitor-settings-to-xorg-conf-d/440518#440518